# c++ push_back правильно ли написал?

Tags: c++, массивы, ооп

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define RETURN return 0

class Dinamic
{
    public:
        Dinamic()
        {
            cout<<"Constructor\t"<<this<<endl;
            size=1;
            arr = new int[size];
        }

        Dinamic(const Dinamic& FromCopy)
        {

        }

        ~Dinamic()
        {
            delete[]arr;
        }
        //methods
        void push_back(const int& value)
        {
            int* NewArr = new int[(this->size+1)];
            for(int i = 0; i < (this->size+1);i++)
            {
                NewArr[i]=this->arr[i];
            }
            NewArr[size]=value;
            size++;
            delete[]arr;
            arr=NewArr;
        }
        void PrintArray()
        {
            for(int i = 1; i < size; i++) 
            {
                cout<<arr[i]<<"\t";
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    private:
    int* arr;
    int size;

};

int main() 
{
    Dinamic l;  
    l.push_back(8);
    l.push_back(8);
    l.PrintArray();

    RETURN;
}
```

у меня все работает хорошо, но в arr[0] где то присваивается 0.
Поэтому я пишу в PrintArray int i = **1**.
Я не могу понять ГДЕ ПРИСВАИВАЕТСЯ 0?
помогите пожалуйста)[image: Вывод]

PrintArray:
int i = 0
[image: Вывод_№2]

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < (this->size+1);i++)` `+1` лишнее чуть что. `for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)` Эм... а чего не с 0?

Comment: в этом то и дело я если пишу с нуля у меня выводится arr[0] в котором ненужный 0

Comment: ну да, не считая того, что вы читали чужую память :D UB оно такое.

Comment: В `arr[0]` не `0`, а мусор, выделенный в конструкторе по умолчанию..

Comment: у меня 0.......

Comment: @ProgrammHeg в такой записи это не гарантируется, хотя _скорее всего_ будет именно 0.

Comment: @ProgrammHeg: Сегодня `0`, завтра `42`... Это не важно. Это случайность. `0` - это такой же мусор как и любое другое неинициализированное значение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы не используете элемент с индексом 0.

1. При создании объекта размер массива должен быть 0, а не 1, как у
   Вас установлено в конструкторе.
2. В конструкторе указатель на массив инициализируйте null.
3. При добавлении элемента проверяйте: если указатель на массив равен
   null, создавайте массив из одного элемента и кладите туда
   добавляемый элемент. Если не null - так, как у Вас уже сделано,
   кроме условия цикла. Должно быть

   j < this->size

Comment: когда я поменял размер в конструкторе на 0 у меня уже все прекрасно заработало зачем 2 и 3

Comment: @ProgrammHeg Может, можно обойтись и без этого, но на мой взгляд, как-то некрасиво создавать массив нулевого размера :)

Comment: НАМана намана, я так всегда делаю))))))))

Answer (score 0):

Если коротко - заменить в конструкторе на

```
size=0;
arr = 0;
```

У вас сразу есть 1 элемент в массиве (вот этот 0) и вы его тащите до конца.

Важно, в коде будет вызван delete[] на null массив. Насколько я знаю, это безопасно.